# method group did you intend to invoke method?

Tags: c#

I'm getting an error off of the following code asking if I want to invoke this method:

```
 protected void CheckForLocalPickPlace(JobList jobs)
    {
        if (CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1 == null)
        {
            CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1 = new Predicate<JobClass>(null, (IntPtr) CheckForLocalPickPlace);
        }
        this.localPickPlace = jobs.TrueForAll(CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1);
    }
```

Comment: Could you tell us what you are trying to do exactly? It's quite unclear. We could try to describe why this won't compile, but that probably won't get you very far with solving your real problem.

Comment: What kind of text editor do you use?  The constructor you're trying to use is normally hidden by the IntelliSense engine since it can only be used by the jitter.  Your editor is getting you into trouble.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the problem is the way you're trying to construct the delegate, although you haven't specified much in the way of types.

You can't build a `Predicate<JobClass>` from `CheckForLocalPickPlace` because the signature is wrong, but if you *could* you could just do:

```
CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1 = CheckForLocalPickPlace;
```

or

```
CachedAnonymousMethodDelegate1 = new Predicate<JobClass>(CheckForLocalPickPlace);
```

If you could give us a lot more context, we can try to help you more.

Answer (score 2):

this.ClearJobs Is that a function? If it is, it should be this.ClearJobs()

Answer (score 1):

Unlike some languages (e.g. Delphi), C# *requires* that you put the brackets after a method to call it.

IIRC, this comes from the definition of the C language where `()` is the *operator* to call a function.

Answer (score 0):

This expression is invalid:

```
new Predicate<JobClass>(null, (IntPtr) CheckForLocalPickPlace)
```

If `CheckForLocalPickPlace` is a method, then you probably meant to put this:

```
new Predicate<JobClass>(CheckForLocalPickPlace)
```

If it is not a method, please describe in more detail what you are trying to do.